# java Playframework GlobalSettings deprecation for onStart

Tags: java, playframework

I have annoying issue with Playframwork deprecated `GlobalSettings` issue, I want to move my conde inside `onStart` to suggested way, but Actually I can't get this done, the documentation make no sense, and I have no idea how to solve this, I spent days and days trying to make it with no luck !

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/GlobalSettings

Simply I want to run initial database method

```
private void initialDB() {
        UserService userService = play.Play.application().injector().instanceOf(UserService.class);
        if (userService.findUserByEmail("email@company.com") == null) {
            String email = "email@company.com";
            String password = "1234";
            String fullName = "My Name";
            User user = new User();
            user.password = BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt());
            user.full_name = fullName;
            user.email = email;
            user.save();
        }
}
```

This was inside `onStart` method in `Global extends GlobalSettings` java file, I tried to extract it to external module but no luck.

```
public class GlobalModule extends AbstractModule {

    protected void configure() {
        initialDB();
    }
}
```

I found some solutions in Scala and no idea how this can be in java, but I have no time to learn it, beside that I don't like it too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need two classes - one to handle the initialization, and a module to register the binding.

The initialization code:

```
@Singleton
public class OnStartup {

    @Inject
    public OnStartup(final UserService userService) {
        if (userService.findUserByEmail("email@company.com") == null) {
            String email = "email@company.com";
            String password = "1234";
            String fullName = "My Name";
            User user = new User();
            user.password = BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt());
            user.full_name = fullName;
            user.email = email;
            user.save();
        }
    }
}
```

The module:

```
public class OnStartupModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        bind(OnStartup.class).asEagerSingleton();
    }
}
```

Finally, add your module to `application.conf`.

```
play.modules.enabled += "com.example.modules.OnStartupModule"
```

By making the singleton eager, it will run when the application is starting up.

Comment: Yes I tried something like that, I reach `OnStartup` but then i'm getting `Error injecting constructor, java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application`

Comment: Oh seems because I access to `Play.application().configuration()` to get configurations.

Comment: Thank you very much, I finally solved my issue :) the issue was complicated, I was trying to access instances should not be called before the application finish starting, I added parameter in constructor `public OnStartup(final UserService userService, final Configuration configuration)`  and access the `configuration` like `configuration.getString("initialName")`

Comment: Apart from Twirl templates, which complicate matters, inject everything.

Comment: How to inject onStop?

Comment: Inject [ApplicationLifecycle](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/java/play/inject/ApplicationLifecycle.html) and use it to register a stop hook.

Comment: From where does the `UserService` get created? I mean, who pass in the `userService` object in the constructor of `OnStartup`

Comment: @Zennichimaro from `@Inject public OnStartup(final UserService userService)` we can infer that `UserService` is known to the DI manager. I would imagine that `UserService` is bound somewhere in a [module](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaDependencyInjection#programmatic-bindings) specific to the project.