# Playframework + Akka: how to avoid excuting scheduled tasks executed when shutdown application

Tags: java, playframework, akka, playframework-2.5

I have issue with scheduler that I start when the play application server start, but once application got shutdown, its hit the following part of code :

```
// firstDay something like 1 = monday 
private void startScheduler(final ImageService imageService,
                            final ActorSystem system) {
    startImagesCleanupScheduler(imageService, system);
    Logger.info("Schedulers started");
}
```

My problem that the `Runnable` block start to execute immediately instead of just cancel the task.

To clarify code:

The following method to start the `Scheduler`:

```
private void startImagesCleanupScheduler(ImageService imageService, ActorSystem system) {
    system.scheduler().schedule(
            Duration.create(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), //Initial delay
            Duration.create(1, TimeUnit.DAYS),     //Frequency 1 days
            () -> {
                int rows = imageService.cleanupInactiveImages();
                Logger.info(String.format("%d inactive unused images cleaned from db", rows));

            },
            system.dispatcher()
    );
}
```

The log when I shutdown note the first line here :

```
[info] - application - 1 inactive unused images cleaned from db
[info] - application - Shutting down connection pool.
[info] - application - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
...
[info] - application - Schedulers started
[info] - play.api.Play - Application started (Prod)
```

You can see it executed the Scheduler ignoring its original execution time, then got shutting down, and then started, and "Schedulers started" after.

What the problem, how I cancel the scheduler or prevent the play to run it before shutdown? is it a bug for Akka?

I'm calling `startScheduler` inside `OnStartup` like the answer of the following question :

[java Playframework GlobalSettings deprecation for onStart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842293/java-playframework-globalsettings-deprecation-for-onstart)

**Edit:**
The following the minimal code to reproduce issue:

First Create `OnStartup` class:

```
@Singleton
public class OnStartup {

    @Inject
    public OnStartup(final ActorSystem system) {
        startScheduler(system);
    }

    private void startScheduler(final ActorSystem system) {
        startImagesCleanupScheduler(system);
        Logger.info("Schedulers started");
    }

    private void startImagesCleanupScheduler(ActorSystem system) {
        system.scheduler().schedule(
                Duration.create(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), //Initial delay
                Duration.create(1, TimeUnit.DAYS),     //Frequency 1 days
                () -> {
                    //int rows = imageService.cleanupInactiveImages();
                    rows = 1;
                    Logger.info(String.format("%d inactive unused images cleaned from db", rows ));
                },
                system.dispatcher()
        );
    }

}
```

Then create module:

```
public class OnStartupModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        bind(OnStartup.class).asEagerSingleton();
    }
}
```

Finally enable module in application.conf :

```
play.modules.enabled += "modules.OnStartupModule"
```

Comment: Can you also post the code you use to start this scheduling, just in case, since this looks ok?

Comment: Already posted in question you may refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842293/java-playframework-globalsettings-deprecation-for-onstart to create on startup, then see code here, its enough to just to print log, comment out the service call

Comment: @AleksandarStojadinovic i provided the simple code

Comment: Currently I only see that you do not need the `@Singleton` annotation, since you are configuring it in the module. That means it is lazily instantiated, while the module declares it as eager. I'm not convinced it is the reason since I don't know the precedence between annotations and modules, but try it.

Comment: I tried that, but seems its Akka system issue, look at this: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/scheduler.html#From_akka_actor_ActorSystem , so i'm looking now for a workaround maybe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit too long for a comment, but I did not test this approach, you might need to tweak it. The documentation says that the components are destroyed in the reverse order they are created. That means you could potentially cancel your scheduler before the `ActorSystem` shuts down, since this class is registered after it and depends on it. Create a shutdown hook like this in your `OnStartup` class in which you will cancel your schedule. That means at the point of the `ActorSystem` shutdown, there will be no schedule to execute:

```
@Singleton
public class OnStartup {

    private final Cancellable cancellableSchedule;

    @Inject
    public OnStartup(final ActorSystem system, final ApplicationLifecycle l) {
        cancellableSchedule = startScheduler(system);
        initStopHook(l);
    }

    private Cancellable startScheduler(final ActorSystem system) {
        return startImagesCleanupScheduler(system);
        Logger.info("Schedulers started");
    }

    private Cancellable startImagesCleanupScheduler(ActorSystem system) {
        return system.scheduler().schedule(
            Duration.create(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), //Initial delay
            Duration.create(1, TimeUnit.DAYS),     //Frequency 1 days
            () -> {
                //int rows = imageService.cleanupInactiveImages();
                rows = 1;
                Logger.info(String.format("%d inactive unused images cleaned from db", rows ));
                },
            system.dispatcher()
        );
    }

    private void initStopHook(ApplicationLifecycle lifecycle) {
       lifecycle.addStopHook(() -> {
            cancellableSchedule.cancel();
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
        });
     }

}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, i'll try it soon

Comment: Any luck with this solution?

Comment: Well, today I was off for 4 days and i'm working again today, coded it but not tried it again, i'll test that in 1 hour :)

Comment: And I tried it, yes solved the problem but with a little fixes, its `.cancel()` instead of `stop()`, and I made a `cancellableSchedule` as a list, and I added instances of Cancellable Schedules into that list and iterate them. (because I was have 2 Schedulers started)

Comment: Great. I'll swap the `stop()` for `cancel()` . As for the list, it was not included in the original question, so for future reference it is probably best to leave it out.

Comment: Thanks, I accepted the question I could provide another answer for list based on your answer.